# RPM spec file: How to link Requires version to BuildRequires version used at build time?

Tags: rpm-spec

Suppose I have this in my spec file:

```
BuildRequires: foo-devel
```

Where I don't care which version of foo is used.

And in

```
%package bar
Summary:
Group:
Requires: foo = %{foo_devel_version}
%description
```

I want to require that foo is same version as foo-devel used in build.
How can I achieve this?

How can I know at build time which version of a `BuildRequires` package I am using?
Is there a builtin solution in rpm, or do I have to do something like `%global foo_devel_version %(rpm -q foo-devel --qf "%{VERSION}")`?

Answer (score 1):

afaik there is no such mechanism in rpmbuild. However, since `rpmbuild` automatically determines your dependencies; and if you correctly use library version (using SONAME); then `rpmbuild` will detect automatically whether you depend on libfoo.so.1 or on libfoo.so.2 . So he will not detect the exact minor version, but should help you on the API level (breaking changes).